# Is the Max Participants setting on Events broken in 5.0?

Tags: civievent, participants

Having recently upgraded to version 5.0 I'm now seeing that although I set the Max Number of Participants at a figure lower than the number of people registered for an event, I can still register for the event through the front end, and I'm not seeing the Event Full message.
Anyone else seeing this issue?

Comment: Are you using Price Sets?

Comment: I am, but that shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just did a test with 5.0.1 and wordpress 4.9.5 and it worked like it should.

Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: Yes, it does look like it was a browser caching issue.  The next day it works fine.

Comment: And now it's not working again?! All caches cleared, and yet the event page is still allowing me to register.

Comment: @Graham have you cleared CiviCRM cache? Is this a recurring event?